# Swapping two rows in a table with unique, not null constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

I have a table with column position, which has unique and not null constraint.

I have move up/down the selected table item requirement,

for that I am taking the selected index and swapping the indexes.

And saving those two items  as in DB.

whenever I am trying to insert first item itself its giving UNIQUE constraint..

Because the item's index is already there in DB.

There is a possibility that I can take temporary index, swapping... and saving .. I think it works.

But is there any other way to achieve this requirement

Answer (score 1):

If you do the update in one Update statement, it'll work fine.

```
create table t (id number primary key);

insert into t values (1);
insert into t values (2);

commit;

update t set id = case when id = 1 then 2 else 1 end
where id in (1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a temporary value like you say because the constraint will not let you have two rows with the same value at any time.

You can probably derive a temporary value that is in itself unique by basing it on the original value and looking at what kind of data you cannot normally have. For example, negative numbers might work.

Other than that, you could declare the constraint as deferred. Then it won't be enforced until the end of your transaction. But that is probably a bit too much effort/impact.

If the field in question is really only used for sorting (and not for object identity), you could consider dropping the uniqueness altogether. You can use a unique primary key as a tie-breaker if necessary.